# Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook is not accepting System.String parameter

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation

I am trying to automate server reboot for one of our environment in Azure through azure automation.
I have created one runbook to know how many servers online.
Then trying pass the output as a parameter to another runbook and getting the 
error.

below is the code.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
# Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
$servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

"Logging in to Azure..."
Add-AzureRmAccount `
    -ServicePrincipal `
    -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
    -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
{
    $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
    throw $ErrorMessage
} else{
    Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
    throw $_.Exception
}
}
$Output = @()
$Running_XenApps = @()
$Output = .\Test.ps1

Foreach ($out in $Output)
{
   $Running_XenApps += $out.Name | Out-String
}


Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook –AutomationAccountName 'acm2eo-azure- automation' -Name 'Server-Reboot' -ResourceGroupName 'acm2eo-automation' -Parameters $Running_Xenapps -Runon acm2eo-hybrid-group1
```

I am getting below error.

```
Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Collections.IDictionary' requiredby parameter 'Parameters'. Specified method is not supported.
```

Please let me know how to convert this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a **hashtable / dictionary** to the `-Parameter` param:

```
$params = @{
    "YourParameterName" = $Running_XenApps
}

Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook –AutomationAccountName 'acm2eo-azure- automation' -Name 'Server-Reboot' -ResourceGroupName 'acm2eo-automation' -Parameters $params  -Runon acm2eo-hybrid-group1
```

As documented here: [`Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook cmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.automation/start-azurermautomationrunbook?view=azurermps-6.2.0).